# How to connect and disconnect mobile to wifi using Appium (java)

Tags: java, android, ios, appium

I need to connect/disconnect iOS and Android devices to/from wifi selecting a specific network from a list of available networks (action to be repeated several times during a test).
Is it possible using Appium?
Is there another workaround for this?

I am using Java + TestNG.
I am not referring to working with Appium via wifi, but connecting and disconnecting as a part of the test.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through settings elements as a simple elements in application. You need to open settings screen, go to wiFi settings and switch to another WiFi. I just checked and it is working. The only thing is that you will have to use only Xpath as i see, but this is only one difficult part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using webdriverio + appium for iOS and Android, and I use this syntax to toggle it. (I believe the syntax is also the same for Java language). Currently using Appium 1.15.1

Wifi

```
driver.toggleWifi();
```

MobileData:

```
driver.toggleData();
```

take note that mobile data toggle has some limitations on Android devices.

For complete documentation of these apis, please check [appium.io](https://appium.io).

Comment: The workaround we used for iOS is to just use manual testing/ manual intervention as it is not currently possible.

Android on the meantime is also problematic, i checked our current implementation and even Android's ADB commands to trigger svc wifi state is affecting the Appium's ability to communicate with the device.

Comment: I just checked that we are not using the code above as it is not working for all devices, so try your luck on it maybe it could work on you.

IOS is not supported so there is no way you can do that via api.